# Should there be a comma before "until" in the following example

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, commas

Should there be a comma before *until* in the following example?

> This process resulted in the middle classes being marginalised, until they were as ostracised as the working classes.

Comment: Did you write this? Or find it somewhere?

Comment: Who gave the down vote before I neutralized it back to zero? And, why was the down vote not accompanied with a comment to explain the reason? That is *not* how we welcome new members to the ELL Exchange. The OP posed a perfectly valid question which elicited a reasonably quality answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally use the until-clause after the main clause. When you do so, you don't use a comma between the main clause and the until-clause.